# log4j and slf4j : %L ,%l printing "?" in log file

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I am using log4j with slf4j for printing logs in a file.
However in patternLayout , tokens like "%l,%L" are printing "?" in log file.
Why it is not printing the source code line number ?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try compiling your sources with full debug symbols. 
For example, here is an extract of `javac` Usage:

> - `-g`                         Generate all debugging info
> - `-g:none`                    Generate no debugging info
> - `-g:{lines,vars,source}`     Generate only some debugging info

If you are using Ant, set the options `debug="true" debuglevel="lines,source"` in your `javac` Ant task.

Comment: Hi,I am using ant to build my project.I added debug=true and debuglevel=line,source in javac task.Still its printing "?".Any clue ?

Comment: Have you also tried with `debuglevel=line,source,vars` ? (i.e. with also *`sources`*)

Comment: Any help please ? I am stuck here.

Comment: See my updated answer for Ant, you may also need to use `debug="true"` with Ant

Comment: Hi xav , i tried that too . .Its not working for me .. Its just printing ?. Any other reason ?